# A particle moves around to the right along the curve $y=\frac3x$

Tags: calculus

A particle moves around to the right along the curve $y=\dfrac {3}{x}$. If its speed is 10 when it passes through the point $\left( 2,\dfrac {3}{2}\right)$, what is its velocity at that time?

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the **derivative at the point** $$\left( 2,\dfrac {3}{2}\right)$$

that is

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{3}{x^2} \implies y'(2)=-\frac34$$

thus the **velocity vector** is

$$\vec v=\lambda(4,-3)$$

and you can find $\lambda$ by the condition on the speed

$$|\vec v|=10$$

that is

$$|\vec v|=\lambda\sqrt{16+9}=5\lambda=10\implies \lambda=2\implies \vec v=(8,-6)$$

Answer (score 2):

The velocity is a vector with length $10$ pointing in the direction of the tangent line to the graph of $y=\frac {3}{x}$ at the given point.Since the slope of the tangent line at the given point is $-3/4$, the component of the velocity are $v_x=8$ and $v_y= -6$

Answer (score 1):

Since $y'=-\dfrac3{x^2}$, at $x=2$ we have that $y'(2)=-\dfrac34\implies \tan^{-1}\left(-\frac34\right)=-36.9^\circ$ to $1$.d.p. so

$$\text{Velocity} \, = 10\, \text{at} \,36.9^\circ \ \text{S of E}.$$